# How does task MSBuild loop over files

Tags: msbuild

```
<Target Name="Build">
...

    <MSBuild
            Projects="$(MSBuildProjectFile)"
            Condition="'@(FilesToCompile)' != ''"
            Targets="buildcpp"
            Properties="CPPFILE=%(FilesToCompile.FullPath);OBJFILE=$(ObjectFolder)\%(FilesToCompile.Filename).doj;IncludeDirs=$(IncludeDirs)"
        />
```

`FilesToCompile` is an `ItemGroup` of all `.cpp` files.

When I look at the build log, it shows the target `buildcpp` being run for each of the files in `CPPFILE`.

I understand that is what I logically want to happen but my question is, what *rule* of element [`<MSBuild>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-task) or the `MSBuild` schema causes task `MSBuild` to be executed for each value of `CPPFILE`?

In short, where in the documentation does it state that is what will happen?

I want to pass in an entire `ItemGroup` once instead of calling the `MSBuild` target once for each item.

Comment: @HansPassant so if I wanted to pass in an entire `ItemGroup` and only once, I would have to first assign it to a `Property` and then set that equal to the `<MSBuild Properties` attribute?

Comment: @HansPassant I want to pass in an `ItemGroup` all at once instead of one Task call per item.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171473.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  msbuild concept this is based on is called "batching" - in your case task batching (see [MSBuild's task batching documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-batching#task-batching)).

Any task that contains a `%()` reference to an item group will be split up into batches that share the same metadata and the task will be executed once for each batch. When using built-in metadata like `Identity` or `FullPath`, this essentially means "execute this task for ever item", though there can also be more complex use cases.