# msbuild - how to do task batching (same project) in parallel

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, msbuild, parallel-builds

Let's say I have this definition

```
<MSBuild
    Projects="$(MSBuildProjectFile)"
    Condition="'@(FilesToCompile)' != ''"
    Targets="buildcpp"
    Properties="CPPFILE=%(FilesToCompile.FullPath);OBJFILE=$(ObjectFolder)\%(FilesToCompile.Filename).doj;IncludeDirs=$(IncludeDirs)"
/>
```

This target is executed multiple times due to [task batching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-batching#task-batching), once for each file in `FilesToCompile`. Importantly, each invocation is completely independent, making it perfect for parallelization.

**QUESTION**

How do I enable "parallel-mode" for [task batching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-batching#task-batching)?

**NOT A DUPLICATE**

I want to invoke the **same target** multiple times with **different property values** and to do that, I need the [batching](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46592182/4784683) to be done in parallel.

The linked question does not do batching and it uses different projects.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I build multiple configurations in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12984882/how-can-i-build-multiple-configurations-in-parallel)

Comment: I don't see how this is different from the linked duplicate: have you tried the sample code of the answer? It builds the same project multiple times with different properties, in parallel. Exactly what you are asking?

Comment: @stijn sample code doesn't iterate over the ItemGroup `FilesToCompile.FullPath`. With the linked solution, I'd have to manually "unwind" the complete item group.

Comment: That is a completely different problem: it's about how to create an ItemGroup which contains the project several times, each with a different value for the Properties metadata. Which you don't have to do manually, you just declare an item using batching. So you don't *need* parallel batching, which would in this case be trying to push a circle through a square hole: just use the canonical MSBuild way, using well-known and built-in functionality.

Comment: @stijn ok. How do I do it?

Comment: Just put what you have for `Properties=...` as metadata in an item. From the top of my head something like `<Proj Include="$(MSBuildProjectFile)"> <Properties>CPPFILE=%(FilesToCompile.FullPath);etc...</Properties>  </Proj>` then `<MSBuild Projects=@(Proj) Targets="buildcpp" BuildInParallel=True"/>`

Answer (score 0):

MSBuild supports parallelism at the project level and in addition for C/C++ projects at CL compiler level. To have MSBuild start using parallelism in your case it is necessary to provide multiple projects and pass them to MSBuild as either (i) a dependency of single project or (ii) solution with defined build graph. In addition it is required to pass `/m` or `/maxcpucount` on a command line to MSBuild and it is advised to use `/nodereuse:false` or `/nr:false`.

In principle you have to create/generate multiple projects each for one invocation of your target.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12984882/how-can-i-build-multiple-configurations-in-parallel: no need to create multiple projects

Answer (score 0):

> How do I enable "parallel-mode" for this task?

To run builds in parallel, we could use `/maxcpucount` switch at a command prompt or [BuildInParallel](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/Microsoft.Build.Tasks.MSBuild.BuildInParallel) task parameter on an MSBuild task. So you should use the `BuildInParallel` task parameter for your task.

The default value of `BuildInParallel` task parameter is `false`, we need set it to `true`:

```
<PropertyGroup>  
    <BuildInParallel Condition="'$(BuildInParallel)' == ''">true</BuildInParallel>  
</PropertyGroup>

<MSBuild
    Projects="$(MSBuildProjectFile)"
    Condition="'@(FilesToCompile)' != ''"
    Targets="buildcpp"
    BuildInParallel="$(BuildInParallel)" 
    Properties="CPPFILE=%(FilesToCompile.FullPath);OBJFILE=$(ObjectFolder)\%(FilesToCompile.Filename).doj;IncludeDirs=$(IncludeDirs)"
/>
```

See [Building Multiple Projects in Parallel with MSBuild](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/building-multiple-projects-in-parallel-with-msbuild) and [new parallel task in the MSBuild Extension Pack](https://mikefourie.wordpress.com/2012/02/29/executing-msbuild-targets-in-parallel-part-1/) for more detail info.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The OP wants to build the same project multiple times with different properties, and do that in parallel.

Comment: I agree with @stijn. I updated the question to explain why it's different than the **potential duplicate**